# What is the point of using an external service provider to send emails?

Tags: email

I'm think of companies like SendGrid or MailGun for example.

Why not just use the hosting server?
Under what circumstances is this useful?

Comment: Because your own server may get blacklisted while services like you mentioned offer their reputation (as long as you play fair).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason - to be "on the track" you have constantly maintain 'image' of your IPs from Email Service Providers point of view and anti-spam services - so you should send not too much and and too low mails, maintain all your DNS records for all IPs, looking for right mail content and do tons of other things.

Services those you mentioned care about most of those I mentioned before - so probability that your mail will be marked as spam is much lower (*bit it still probable so you still have to care about your mail text and composition*).

There is a good article that describes all difficulties with own hosted mass mail infrastructure - [So You'd Like to Send Some Email (Through Code)](https://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/).

It referenced from one of [FAQ point from MailGun site "Why not just use Sendmail + Postfix + Courier IMAP?"](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faqs.html#why-not-just-use-sendmail-postfix-courier-imap) - that also got reasonable explanation.

That is why, for example, we use SMTP Relay proxies.